# Problem in Joining RHEL with Windows 2008

Tags: rhel, domain, active-directory

I configured Domain on my test machine (Win2k8) and domain name is **win2008ad.local** and computer name is win2k8. So the full name is **win2k8.win2008ad.local**.

I installed packages on RHEL 5 related to winbind, Samba, and KRB

After doing all the configurations when i run this command 
**net ads join -U administrator** it gives me this error

[image]

and **wbinfo -u** gives this error
*Error Looking up Domain Users*

Contents of `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf`:

```
#
# pam_winbind configuration file
#
# /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf
#

[global]

# turn on debugging
;debug = yes

# request a cached login if possible
# (needs "winbind offline logon = yes" in smb.conf)
;cached_login = yes

# authenticate using kerberos
krb5_auth = yes

# when using kerberos, request a "FILE" krb5 credential cache type
# (leave empty to just do krb5 authentication but not have a ticket
# afterwards)
;krb5_ccache_type = FILE

# make successful authentication dependend on membership of one SID
# (can also take a name)
;require_membership_of =
```

Contents of `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[root@rhmain ~]# cat /etc/krb5.conf
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = WIN2008AD.LOCAL
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes

[realms]
 #EXAMPLE.COM = {
  #kdc = kerberos.example.com:88
  #admin_server = kerberos.example.com:749
  #default_domain = example.com
  WIN2008AD.LOCAL = {
  kdc = win2k8.win2008ad.local
  admin_server = win2k8.win2008ad.local
}

[domain_realm]
 #.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 #example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 .win2k8.win2008ad.local = WIN2008AD.LOCAL

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.20.20.221    win2k8.win2008ad.local  winad
```

Contents of `/etc/nsswitch`:

```
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files
group:      files winbind
```

Contents of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     required      pam_winbind.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

And finally `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
security = ads
realm = WIN2008AD.LOCAL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

#### kinit

Did you run this command after finishing your setup?

```
kinit administrator@WIN2008AD.LOCAL
```

#### SRV records

Do you have proper SRV DNS records? Run this type of command to confirm:

```
host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.TLD
```

You'll need to adujust the subdomain.domain.tld portion for your particular setup.